# Firebase Java POJOs and local-only fields

Tags: java, firebase, pojo

Given the following POJO example which stores local fields applicable only to the app running right here, nobody else whom also use the Firebase data:

```java
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class DispatchModel {
    private String isotimestamp;
    private String date_time;
    private String event_uuid;
    //...
    private String locallyCreatedValue;
    //...constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Given my Firebase data has the first three fields stored in it, and the locallyCreatedValue is added to my POJO during app runtime, is there a way to automatically fetch all the locally added content from a POJO instance and apply to the new instance when an update from onChildChanged event happens?

As it is right now, I'll have to manually obtain all the local field values and set them on the new instance:

```java
@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    DispatchModel newModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(DispatchModel.class);
    // get list index of expiring instance
    // get instance of old item at list index
    // index = ...
    // old = ...

    // repeat this for every local item :-/
    newModel.setLocallyCreatedValue(old.getLocallyCreatedValue);

    dispatchList.set(index, newModel);
}
```

I plan on having quite a few local fields, is this my only option? Are there any functions Firebase offers that makes their automatic object instantiation more friendly to my extras? I'm not keen on creating distinct POJOs to track the Firebase POJOs in parallel. That lends to data errors from decoupled data updates and careful schedules for execution.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your locally created values are expressed as standard getters and setters in your POJO, you are either going to have to copy them manually, or write some fairly intense Java reflection code to inspect the class, somehow figure out which properties are local (annotation? inclusion/exclusion from a known list?) and should be copied over, then actually do that work.  You will not be able to get this "for free" using some utility (unless there happens to be some third party library that has solved this specific problem, and I doubt it).

Consider instead maybe storing your locally created values as a Map, then simply copying that map wholesale between objects. But then you have unknown types for the values if they're all different.

Or rewrite your code in JavaScript, which has easy property enumeration.  :-)